# MyBatis Spring Transactions

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-transactions

I'm trying to properly use spring transaction-management functionality provided by [MyBatis](https://mybatis.org/spring/transactions.html)

I'm creating `sqlSessionFactor` in the following manner:

```xml
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:some/package/**/*.xml" />
    <property name="transactionFactory">
        <beanclass="org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransactionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

```sql
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Now there is this section called "Programmatic Transaction Management" [here](https://mybatis.org/spring/transactions.html) which gets the reference of `transactionManager` and using this `transactionManager` we are doing `rollback` or `commit` depending upon whether we got an exception or not.

Now my question is that in my DAO layer should I explicitly do something like

```java
public class UserDao extends SqlSessionDaoSupport {
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager; // wired using bean-property

    public void insertUser(Integer userId) {
        try {
            getSqlSession().insert("user-map.insertUser", userId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transactionManager.rollback(txStatus);
            throw e;
        }
        transactionManager.commit(txStatus);
    }
}
```

or just using the following thing (without programmatic transactions) will also perform all the insertions in a transactional way.

```java
public class UserDao extends SqlSessionDaoSupport {

    public void insertUser(Integer userId) {
        getSqlSession().insert("user-map.insertUser", userId);
    }
}
```

my mapper file looks something like this:

```xml
<insert id="insertUser" parameterType="HashMap">
    <!-- this contains multiple insert queries -->
</insert>
```

Note that I've multiple inserts inside `<insert>...</insert>` and I want either all of them to happen or non-of them to happen.

[This](https://mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html) is another reference that I was using.

**So a general question is that will MyBatis provide an automatic transaction-management around my `<insert>...</insert>` or will I have to explicitly use the `transactionManager` to achieve the transaction-management feature?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the quote from the documentation you referenced:

> MyBatis `SqlSession` provides you with specific methods to handle transactions programmatically. But when using MyBatis-Spring your beans will be injected with a Spring managed `SqlSession` or a Spring managed mapper. That means that Spring will always handle your transactions.

With the setup you provided transaction timespan is completely managed by spring that is if 
you use [declarative transaction management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) you don't need to do anything additionally. Spring will start transaction at the point it is directed to by your configuration.

The simple way to enable declarative transaction management is to add this to spring configuration:

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

And then use `@Transactional` on your service methods:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
  @Autowired
  private UserDao userDao;

  @Transactional
  public addUser(User user) {
     userDao.insertUser(user);
  }
}
```

The section in the documentation you mentioned is about the (rare) cases when you want to use programmatic transaction management.